# DataGridView CellPainting: Highlight word in cell considering cell's content direction

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, highlighting, paintevent

This is the case: I want to search for a word in a whole `DataGridView` through looping it's `Row`s, and then for each match I highlight the word. The major inflexibility I face is that columns have different `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment`s. So in paiting (highlighting) mathced word in cells I should take care of cell's `ContentAlignment`.

So far I have written the following code to find the matches

```
private int FindAllMatches()
{
    int itemsFound = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < dgvMain.Rows.Count; r++)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dgvMain.Rows[r];
        for (int c = 0; c < Columns.Count; c++)
        {
            string cellValue = (dgvMain.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value ?? "").ToString();
            if (cellValue.Contains(SearchValue.ToString()))
            {
                HighlightRow(row); // highlights whole row, weak solution
                itemsFound++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return itemsFound;
}
```

But as you see I have currently managed to highlight the rows which have at least one match. What I need is a code to highlight only the portion of cell which matches my specific word (*SearchValue*).

I know I should use the `CellPainting` Event, but I don't know how to paint the word inside a `Cell` considering the `Cell`'s `ContentAlignment`

Comment: I have answered [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21989469/set-two-colors-text-in-a-single-datagridview-cell/21997432#21997432)

Comment: Hi @Junaith, in the last couple of weeks I have been asking about `DataGridView` and you have been answering them :) I think we should start a business together ;) kidding. I'll check it and let you know in a couple of minutes ...

Comment: I've got a problem @Junaith, your code is fine for English text, but my language is Persian that is written in `RightToLeft` direction. With the [Current Answer you have provided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21989469/set-two-colors-text-in-a-single-datagridview-cell/21997432#21997432) my text is shown wrong, for example if my cell text is 'نصب قفل سخت افزاری' it is shown like 'فزاری  نصب قفل سخت ا'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21989469/set-two-colors-text-in-a-single-datagridview-cell/21997432#21997432) to consider the direction and content alignment. It works for default alignment but you have to improve the code for other alignments.

```
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex != -1 && e.Value != null && e.Value.ToString().Length > 5 && e.ColumnIndex == 2)
    {
        if (!e.Handled)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected);
        }
        if ((e.PaintParts & DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground) != DataGridViewPaintParts.None)
        {
            bool rightToLeft = this.RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes ? true:false;
            string text = e.Value.ToString();
            string textPart1 = text.Substring(0, text.Length - 5);
            string textPart2 = text.Substring(text.Length - 5, 5);
            Size fullsize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, e.CellStyle.Font);
            Size size1 = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textPart1, e.CellStyle.Font);
            Size size2 = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textPart2, e.CellStyle.Font);
            Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.Location, e.CellBounds.Size);
            TextFormatFlags flags = GetFlagsForCellStyleAlignment(rightToLeft, e.CellStyle.Alignment);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text, e.CellStyle.Font, rect1, Color.Crimson, flags);
            using (Brush cellForeBrush = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.ForeColor))
            {
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, textPart1, e.CellStyle.Font, rect1, e.CellStyle.ForeColor, flags);
            }
        }
    }
}

TextFormatFlags GetFlagsForCellStyleAlignment(bool rigthToLeft, DataGridViewContentAlignment alignment)
{
    TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.Default;
    switch (alignment)
    {
        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopLeft:
            {
                flags = TextFormatFlags.Default;
                if (rigthToLeft)
                {
                    flags |= TextFormatFlags.Right;
                }
                break;
            }
        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft:
            {
                flags = TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;
                if (rigthToLeft)
                {
                    flags |= TextFormatFlags.Right;
                }
                break;
            }
    }
    if (rigthToLeft)
        flags |= TextFormatFlags.RightToLeft;
    return flags;
}
```

Comment: Good code for a start, but not complete. Your code acts differently when the cell `StartsWith` a word and when it `Contains` the word in it and does not start with it.

Comment: By the way, I have changed your code. So it's not your fault. Code should be worked on...

Comment: Yeah I know... but it will be challenging as you have to change the text alignment based on where your colored letters are in the word.

Comment: I'm working on it, but it would be great if you could give me a more complete sample, not because I want it to be easier, because I don't understand some parts and get confused.

Comment: Ok I will try... Do you want to highlight full word or one word in a sentence like Hello **World** or multiple words in a sentence like Hello **World**, Nice to **meet** you or letters in a word like **pass**ive.

Comment: Thanks a lot, actually I want to highlight a word but if it occurs multiple times in a cell all of them should get highlighted. For example: **If** my code is d**if**erent from your code, any **if** in it should be counted sign**if**icantly.

Comment: Then I would suggest you to have a custom DataGridViewRitchTextBoxColumn...you can achieve your highlighting easily... I am remember answering a question with link to an article for RichTextColumn...you can search it

Comment: I think you mean [Access RitchTextBox Control ...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20973851/1471381) answer, but I'm doing this for search and not in edit mode.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49547/discussion-between-mahdi-tahsildari-and-junaith)